# Facebook Send To Messenger Doesn't Send Anything To Server

Tags: facebook

How to use Webhook event that been provided for Send To Messenger plugin, messaging_optins?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_optins

After user click Send To Messenger button and connect with their Messenger account, the button doesn't send anything to the server. Are there anything that I'm missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, figured it on my own. Ended up page access token that connect with the apps already expired.